# obj-c cannot find index from searched array / wrong output

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, indexing, nspredicate

Whatever I do in whatever combination, `NSLog` always returns a wrong index-number of the successfully searched array-object.

code:

```
-(void)secondbuttonClickedDivi:(id)sender{
    UIButton *xbutton = (UIButton *)sender;
    // NSLog(@"%@arraysucks",);
    //NSArray *subviews = [self.coview subviews];

    // same bogus oupit of index like in  [self.coview subviews] :
    NSArray *subviews= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:xbutton,nil];
    NSLog(@"%@subarray",subviews);
    NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tag = %ld%@", [sendertag],@";"];
    // test search .
    NSString *dummysearch= @"tag = 54;";
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@" : search", search);
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@" : search",dummysearch);
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subviews CONTAINS %@",search];
    NSLog(@"%@predicate", predicate);
    NSArray *filteredArray = [subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSString *findtag =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", predicate];

    NSString *gettag = [findtag substringFromIndex:  24];
    NSString *lastget = [gettag substringToIndex:NSMaxRange([gettag rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:2])];
    long value = [lastget longLongValue];
    NSLog(@"findtag: %@", gettag);
    NSLog(@"lastget: %@", lastget);

    NSLog(@"%ldvalue",value);
    if(_checkstate==2){
        _checkstate=1;

        if([sender tag]!= value){
            [[subviews objectAtIndex:value]  setTitle:_resetbuttonTitle     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            xbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@dsendertag",_resetbuttonTitle);
    NSLog(@"%ldsendertag",[sender tag]);
    NSInteger anIndex=[filteredArray indexOfObject:xbutton];
    NSLog(@"%ld : isIndex",anIndex);
}
```

NSLog output:

```
 (
  UIButton: 0x7fdf1a422550; frame = (161 281; 42 42); opaque = NO; tag = 48; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000224ee0>>
)subarray
  : searchtag = 48;
  : searchtag = 54;
 subviews CONTAINS "tag = 48;"predicate
findtag:  48;"
 lastget:  48
 48value
 48:6dsendertag
 48sendertag
 9223372036854775807 : isIndex
 1checkstate
```

Except the bogus index-output  all array-search is successful, but what I really need is the index.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be trying to use `NSPredicate` to find a view inside the array with its tag. In that case you're doing it incorrectly. You should do that instead:

```
NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.tag = %ld", [sender tag]];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:search];
NSArray *filteredArray = [subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Reference: 
[How to filter a NSArray of subviews by tag using NSPredicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154067/ios-how-to-filter-a-nsarray-of-subviews-by-tag-using-nspredicate)

Also, 9223372036854775807 is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in hexadecimal, which is the unsigned representation of -1 in 64 bit variables, which is the case of NSInteger (long int). When `indexOfObject:` returns -1, that's because the object isn't in the array.

Basically, filteredArray doesn't contains xbutton since the predicate was done incorrectly. You can confirm that by printing filteredArray with NSLog.

Comment: :excellent explanation, you saved my day (or my coffee-night) :-)

NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.tag = %ld", [sender tag]]; 
was the solution for filteredArray.
 Now I can do  : NewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:filteredArray];
--
  [[NewArray objectAtIndex:0]  setTitle:_resetbuttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            xbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [NewArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
--
if ([NewArray count] == 0){
...  }
 else if ...
--
thank you!